# Is this a valid way to minimize binding invalidations?

Tags: java, javafx, concurrency, javafx-8

I have some complex Observable structures, which may or may not be bad ideas, but which are not the focus of this question.

The problem with those structures is that they generate a lot of invalidations of `Observable` objects being displayed by the UI.  As near as I can tell, when the JavaFX UI is displaying something, it registers a `ChangeListener` on it, so any attempts to use lazy evaluation go out the window.  That is, invalidating the observable seems to tell the UI that it has potentially changed, which causes the UI to *immediately* request it's value, forcing it to evaluate immediately.

So, I had the idea of deferring the invalidations via `Platform.runLater()`.

I created a class called `DeferredBinding` that delegates everything to a wrapped `Binding`, except the `invalidate()` method, which it defers to the JavaFX UI thread to be processed later.  It seems to work... I can invalidate a hundred times and it only seems to actually process the invalidation once.

But, I've not seen this pattern before and I am afraid it might fall into the category of "nice try but bad idea".

So, question: is this a bad idea?  I am particularly concerned of errors introduced into other `Observable` objects that depend on the `DeferredBinding`.  Will they be fine once the `Platform.runLater()` happens?

```
package com.myapp.SAM.model.datastructures;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.binding.Binding;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

/**
 * Specialized binding that defers its invalidations to the JavaFX UI thread in a throttled manner. The idea being that, if invalidate() is called many times,
 * it only basically happens once (when the UI thread gets to it).
 */
public class DeferredBinding<T> implements Binding<T> {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DeferredBinding.class.getName());

    private final Binding<T> binding;

    private final AtomicBoolean pendingInvalidation = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public DeferredBinding(Binding<T> binding) {
        this.binding = binding;
    }

    @Override
    public void addListener(ChangeListener<? super T> listener) {
        binding.addListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeListener(ChangeListener<? super T> listener) {
        binding.removeListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public T getValue() {
        return binding.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public void addListener(InvalidationListener listener) {
        binding.addListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeListener(InvalidationListener listener) {
        binding.removeListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid() {
        return binding.isValid();
    }

    /**
     * Override logic for invalidate() method to defer invalidation to runLater. Throttle the invalidations so as not to floor the JavaFX UI thread with
     * multiple calls
     */
    @Override
    public void invalidate() {
        if (pendingInvalidation.getAndSet(true) == false) {
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                // Signal that the UI is processing the pending invalidation, so any additional invalidations must schedule another update.
                pendingInvalidation.set(false);
                binding.invalidate();
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableList<?> getDependencies() {
        return binding.getDependencies();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        binding.dispose();
    }

}
```

Comment: It is similar to the mechanism used in the Service implementation to avoid flooding the UI with updates, but there you have a separate thread with potentially lots of updates.

My worry would be why you have a structure where you need to update the same properties over and over in a single action.

Comment: It's a complex structure involving aggregates.  I have a `List` and the UI needs to display aggregates and computations based on those aggregates constantly, in real time.  The problem is if I need to update, say, 60,000 elements in the `List`, the aggregates are recomputed 60,000 times (and only the last one is really relevant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not try to solve performance problems ahead of time. Measure your application to determine if you have a problem and then go ahead..

Let's assume you have a problem, there are many ways to solve your abstract problem. Three solutions come to my mind:

**1**

Coalesce updates (`Platform.runLater()`) to prevent saturation of the FX event queue as you have done in your example.

And since you are just invalidating the binding you do not have to fear loosing a value on the way. So it seems (without knowing the full application) that this way should work.

---

**2**

Using the `Node`s built-in behavior of marking regions dirty for (re-)layouting. At some point you will call `javafx.scene.Parent.requestLayout()` (this is the "invalidation") which will at some point in the future call `javafx.scene.Parent.layoutChildren()` to apply the dirty attributes to the region.

---

**3**

Using solution 2 in a different way: By using a virtualized layout container. The `TableView`, `TreeTableView` and `ListView` all use the virtualized approach to update only the visible cells.
See `com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow` and `com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualContainerBase` for some JDK examples, another example would be the [Flowless API](https://github.com/TomasMikula/Flowless).

As you did not tell any specifics I can not guide you any further. But it should be clear, that your approach may very well work and there are other ways.